# not printing the right value from input file

Tags: c

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here? basically I've written some code that should take values from a file and then print the first value from the file as output along with the number of values in the file.

Although I get the correct number of values, my first value printed in the output isn't the same as the first value in my file. here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const char Project_Data[] = "filedata.dat";
    FILE *input = fopen(Project_Data, "r");

    int t = 0;
    int N = 0;
    float *a;

    a = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

    if(input != (FILE*) NULL)
    {
        while(fscanf(input, "%e", &a[t]) == 1)
        {
            N++;
            if(a[t] == EOF)
                break;
        }

        printf("first value in file: %e\n",a[0]);
        printf("number of values in file: %d\n", N);
    }
    else
        printf("coudlnt read input file.\n");

    return(0);
}
```

I feel it's got something to do with how I'm using the malloc function. If so, how do I use it correctly? I want to read my values from the file into an array size N, but how can I do that if I don't know the value of N beforehand?

---

EDIT:

Here's some of the values from the file. The values are ordered one after the other with a single space between them. Because the number of values is quite large, they kind of form a several diagonals across the page (if you've it before).

```
   9.0100000e+00   8.9663752e-01
   9.0200000e+00   1.5041077e+00
   9.0300000e+00   2.5992505e+00
   9.0400000e+00   1.5242828e+00
   9.0500000e+00   3.6815660e-01
   9.0600000e+00   5.4889676e-01
   9.0700000e+00   1.2371257e+00
   9.0800000e+00   1.2163317e+00
   9.0900000e+00   5.4318479e-01
   9.1000000e+00   1.5906641e+00
   9.1100000e+00   2.6775285e+00
   9.1200000e+00   1.1608307e+00
   9.1300000e+00   1.2084299e+00
   9.1400000e+00  -7.8752191e-01
   9.1500000e+00   6.4048690e-01
   9.1600000e+00   2.2727416e-02
   9.1700000e+00   1.0307653e+00
   9.1800000e+00   1.9435864e+00
   9.1900000e+00   2.9422693e+00
   9.2000000e+00   3.2184945e+00
   9.2100000e+00   1.3041157e+00
   9.2200000e+00   1.1018038e+00
```

The values on the left aren't orders; they are genuine values, it's just the other data is meant to be the 'noise' in the data i think.

Comment: Can you post the input file - atleast a part of it?

Comment: yes of course - i will edit my post now

Comment: `a[t] == EOF`?!? (Yes, EOF is an `int`, but I very much doubt you want this...

Comment: Editorial note - it's unnecessary (and unidiomatic) to cast the return value of `malloc()` like that in a C program.  The conversion from `void *` is implicit.

Comment: Yup, your `malloc(N * sizeof(float))` is completely broken: `N` is 0 at that point, so you aren't asking for memory at all. Whatever happens next is undefined behaviour, all bets are off.

Comment: ok - i understand what you're all saying and i wasn't sure either. does anyone see what i'm trying to do though? basically i want an array a[N-1] size but how do I create that array if i don't know N beforehand?

Comment: and i guess this is why my value is wrong too?

Comment: `while(fscanf(input, "%e", &a[t]) == 1)` shouldn't this be `while(fscanf(input, "%e", &a[t]) == EOF)` instead?
As @vonbrand mentioned, I don't think fscanf would save the EOF into a[t]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allocate an array with, say, 10 elements at first. While reading the file, remember to increase the index variable (t in your example). Should t become greater than your allocated size, use realloc to double the size of your array. This is how most dynamic vector implementations work as far as I know.

Something like this:

```
int capacity = 10;
float* a = (float*)malloc(capacity*sizeof(float));
int t = 0;    

while(fscanf(input, "%e", &a[t]) == 1) {
   t++;
   if (t >= capacity) {
      capacity *= 2;
      void* temp = realloc(a, capacity*sizeof(float));
      if (temp == 0) exit(1); // or handle allocation failure properly, a is still valid
      a = (float*)temp;
   }
}
```

At this point `a` should contain your items and `t` the number of items read.

Comment: What you suggested works! Thank you so much - I definitely understand your line of thought too so hopefully I shouldn't have this problem again (additionally thank you the person below me who commented with the same idea, it really is appreciated).

Comment: Please don't use `realloc` like that.  If you don't assign to a temporary variable, `realloc` failures will cause memory leaks of `a`.

Comment: Hmmm, I've since done some reading regarding how realloc should be used and I get what you're saying. I've been trying what @jakber suggested above but now, when I try to print part of my array, nothing happens. I shall continue to fiddle around with a few things and hopefully get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

a = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

Since N is set to 0, you're allocating 0 bytes? That seems very buggy.

Comment: I know - but I'm not sure how else do it? I've tried various different things but I can't seem to get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not first allocate the array to a big arbitrary number such as 1024, and then if you really do need to save on space, realloc down after you know how much input you will receive?
and if you do get more than 1024 entries, you realloc to 2048 and keep saving values?